# How do I form an SQL query to show entire column of dates with modified values?

Tags: mysql, date, interval

Assume that I have a table **Purchases** with column named **PurchaseDate** and with data format of 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'.
Suppose that I want to see the entire column of dates with the days increasing by 5.

Suppose I form the query in the following way:

```
SELECT PurchaseDate+5 FROM Purchases;
```

The result will be given in a form of single numbers, and the increased part will be seconds instead of days.
I.e.: This 1982-09-07 00:00 will turn into this 198209070005.

**How do I form the right standard SQL query?**

**UPDATE:** **I've got answer.** Thanks.

-- this will work for standard SQL:

```
SELECT PurchaseDate, PurchaseDate + INTERVAL 5 DAY FROM Purchases;
```

-- this will work for MySQL:

```
SELECT PurchaseDate, ADDDATE(PurchaseDate, INTERVAL 10 DAY) FROM Purchases;
```

Comment: Whereby does the `05` at the end come from? Your time is is `00:00`, so shouldn't the time second part be `000000`? Five `0`s because there are 86400 seconds in a day! Please provide the output of show create table your_table\G; indicating the relevant field. A couple of sample inserts would be good also! Please also provide your version of MySQL. p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: Added the images with sample query output.  
MySql is of most recent version (MySQL Community Server 8.0.18 ).

Comment: Screenshots are [discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530) here for reasons outlined in the link. Please post what I asked for - the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE my_tab\G` as text. We need to know the datatypes of your fields. Are you transforming a real date into a string (e.g. `1948-12-08 00:00:00` → `'19481208000005'`)? I'm having difficulty in understanding your request - what is the reason for this particular transformation? What is the new datum's datatype?How do you subsequently use that transformed data?

Comment: _Are you transforming a real date into a string_ - No, this was undesired behavior. And i don't know the reason behind removal of DATE data type; This is a part of my question. But i've got desired results after double check. _The Answer below is correct and suitable._

Comment: `INTERVAL 5 DAY` is **not** "standard SQL". `INTERVAL '5' DAY` would be standard SQL

Comment: You should be using the correct data type for a given datum - otherwise it can confuse the optimiser. Using home-made functions to do date arithmetic is error-prone. If you want to use `INTEGER`s, then use the [UNIX time functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) - check out the other functions on that page. [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=967afaf52f587553081f89ca36da92ee) are a couple of examples of their use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asuming the column has a datetime type, simply:

```
SELECT PurchaseDate + INTERVAL 5 DAY FROM
```

If it was a string type, you would have to parse it first.

Comment: Is this expression valid for MySql only? AFAIK, standard SQL does not recognize INTERVAL. Does standard SQL have means to do the same?

Comment: interval is a standard sql92 type- which RDBMS implement it and how, I don't know. You can always use also a function like `ADDDATE(PurchaseDate, 5)`, but that is definitely MySQL-only.

Comment: You right, **Your first answer is a standard SQL query. Marked as answer.** 
`SELECT OrderDate, ADDDATE(OrderDate, INTERVAL 10 DAY) FROM Orders;` Yes. **This will work for MySQL.**